# Find and replace the exact match in a file - change the value of something in a file - linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, sed, find-and-replace

**1) I have a file : /etc/testconfig/users.conf :**

```
john1:*:$5$CJ5q52R0DPTbnvfddsa3IB/lofFuRoFnFc3OgKxkDP520PntI8pI76
john43:*:$5$cSV2tbDHA5645gdfN5w8W2TDMddyOPMBUR9nL7hQoVwF6QddElClKji/PB
54john:*:$5$7HKalMq5mwN8Q0.R$tr.1LntkXmMGP7ury7BozfGFPoRVbgRTBxgA86kBh65
john:*:$5$Y8EaseV3CsfdfgU$pCcQNC4o1m9H3NhiTXQ6sIDE5qOGNEsEuEGl8tXAq3B
john20:*:$5$YadICtwvyrVdfcvhGT8VVy5tyhg5bWtAlMfc/wwqs8K3ngvLM6
johndoe:*:$5$fq9F07dfgfgh56756yhgLBYCEQpdRmRBzl0RU.q1ZLj7DsT1.kiCCF9
```

My goal is find and replace the exact match in my file.

I tried :

```
  sed -i "s/john/david/" /etc/testconfig/users.conf
```

But all the Johns in the file replaced with David :

```
david1:*:$5$CJ5q52R0DPTbnvfddsa3IB/lofFuRoFnFc3OgKxkDP520PntI8pI76
david43:*:$5$cSV2tbDHA5645gdfN5w8W2TDMddyOPMBUR9nL7hQoVwF6QddElClKji/PB
54david:*:$5$7HKalMq5mwN8Q0.R$tr.1LntkXmMGP7ury7BozfGFPoRVbgRTBxgA86kBh65
david:*:$5$Y8EaseV3CsfdfgU$pCcQNC4o1m9H3NhiTXQ6sIDE5qOGNEsEuEGl8tXAq3B
david20:*:$5$YadICtwvyrVdfcvhGT8VVy5tyhg5bWtAlMfc/wwqs8K3ngvLM6
daviddoe:*:$5$fq9F07dfgfgh56756yhgLBYCEQpdRmRBzl0RU.q1ZLj7DsT1.kiCCF9
```

**2) My second question is how can I change the value of something.**

In this file : /etc/testconfig/test.conf :

I want to change the value of test-example :

```
#this is the test-example  with the test-example you can do something.
test-example = 25
```

to

```
#this is the test-example. with the test-example you can do something.
test-example = 45
```

without replacing the entire line(Just change 25 to 45).
The test-example value (25) may vary. So I can't find and change it with constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
sed -i "s/\bjohn\b/david/" /etc/testconfig/users.conf
```

---

Use capture group:

```
sed -i "s/\(test-example = \)[0-9]\+/\1 45/" /etc/testconfig/users.conf
```

Comment: thanks my friend it worked. do you have a solution for my second question?

Comment: @Bandit1989: see my edit.

Comment: thank you. This worked too. But when I use this command once, it enters the new value with a space. And this causes it to not work if I re-enter the command for the new value. I mean, it adds an extra space. It changes test-example = 25  to test-example =(space)(space)45

Comment: @Bandit1989: Move the space outside the parens: `s/\(test-example =\) [0-9]\+/\1 45/`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry my friend The problem was on my side. problem solved. Thank you. cheers